# Download BinaryFiled Data

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

how to download BinaryField Data/file using template. like we did for FileField.

```
<td><a href={{certificate.bytes.url}} download></a>
```

I past all url.py and view.py file below please look This may give extract view of my code. and please help me with this i am new to Django. ............................................................................................................................................................

> url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^list/create$', views.certificate_create, name='certificate_create'),
    url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/update$', views.certificate_update, name='certificate_update'),
    url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/delete$', views.certificate_delete, name='certificate_delete'),
    path('download',views.download, name = 'download'),


]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we need Django models which contains BinaryField for example.

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    image = models.BinaryField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'person'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('download/<int:pk>/', views.download, name='download'),
]
```

## views.py

```
import io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import FileResponse
from .models import Person

def index(request):
    # there are listed all models.
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'persons': persons})

def download(request, pk):
    # this url is for download
    try:
        obj = Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Person.DoesNotExist as exc:
        return JsonResponse({'status_message': 'No Resource Found'})
    get_binary = obj.image
    if get_binary is None:
        return JsonResponse({'status_message': 'Resource does not contian image'})
    if isinstance(get_binary, memoryview):
        binary_io = io.BytesIO(get_binary.tobytes())
    else:
        binary_io = io.BytesIO(get_binary)
    response = FileResponse(binary_io)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-binary'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.png"'.format(pk) # You can set custom filename, which will be visible for clients.
    return response
```

## index.html

```
{% for person in persons %}
    <a href="{% url 'download' pk=person.pk %}">{{ person.name }}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

This is solution to send binary file from server and download. All components are shown. Good luck !

Comment: getting error :Reverse for 'download' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 201}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['SharedApps_Application/download$']

Comment: In URL.py i put this:  path('download',views.download, name = 'download'),

Comment: Yes, of course !. You should adopt code for your project.

Comment: Updated answer, includes urls.py also.

Comment: one more error : AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tobytes'

Comment: in line  **image = io.BytesIO(obj.image.tobytes())**

Comment: which version of django you use and python ?

Comment: python: 3.7.1  , Django: 2.1.7

Comment: image = io.BytesIO(obj.image.tobytes() if not isinstance(obj.image, bytes) else obj.image)

Comment: not working getting error:  
local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

Comment: Ok, just set correct extensions for client. Like .png, .jpg and so on.